# android speech recognition beside english

Tags: android

When using Google Translate, you can switch to russian speech recognition,but how can I to implement Google russian speech engine in a Android phone?

Right now, I can use default Google English speech engine, is there possible I can choose the different language, such as  Japanese, Spanish, French etc..(i mean at google voice recognition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_LANGUAGE) when you call the recognizer.